# Android Push Notification Not opening the Activity if n number of notifications in Notification Bar

Tags: android, android-activity, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing an android app and i am implemented GCM push notification also,and notification id is different for each,The problem is When i have n push notifications and app is not in background ,When i click on the notification first time it will open the activity. Then i again cleared the app instance from background and  clicked  on the another push notification it will not open the app.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
    long[] vibrate = {0, 100, 200, 300};
    Uri notification = RingtoneManager
            .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                    | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Bitmap largIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.small_icon_notification)
            .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setLargeIcon(largIcon)
            .setSound(notification)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(msg).      setSound(notification)
            .setStyle((new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()).bigText(msg)) .setAutoCancel(true);
    mBuilder.setVibrate(vibrate);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: I don't think you should be casting System.currentTimeMillis() into int. Use a random number generator instead.

Comment: I changed notification id as you said. But result is the same

Comment: Can you update the code with your changes?

Answer (score 1):

In the line(s)

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

you always use the same request code for the `PendingIntent`.

All instances of `PendingIntent` with the same request code (first argument) and same intent (maybe even that is unimportant, I did not test that yet) are the same pending intent, no matter what extras you put to the intent. The only way to make them different is to use different request codes.

Especially if you use the `FLAG_ONE_SHOT`, a  ["Flag indicating that this PendingIntent can be used only once"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_ONE_SHOT)

Answer (score 0):

I removed `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT` and pending intent request code to a random number. Now it works fine.